# Yeoman built angular app not deploying bootstrap fonts to heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, yeoman

**Upfront, I've already solved this bug. This is just reference for others who run into it.**

I've deployed a Yeoman-built app to heroku using this guide: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/

The guide worked nearly flawlessly except needing to remove the line:

```
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
```

Once deployed, the glyphicons packaged with bootstrap are were returning a 404. After much digging around I realized the:

```
dist/bower_components
```

folder was not being added to the git repository due to this line inside my .gitignore:

```
// .gitignore file //
node_modules
.tmp
.sass-cache
bower_components // This line!
```

Deleting meant submitting my entire bower_components folder to the git repository, which I didn't see as necessary. Instead, I added the following to .gitignore:

```
// .gitignore file //

node_modules
.tmp
.sass-cache
bower_components
!dist/bower_components
```

Now the dist/bower_components gets added to the repository and will deploy to Heroku, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Nice post, Eric. I ran into these problems as well when trying to get my angualr yeoman project up and running on heroku. I would add that if you want to run something like logger, it is now called morgan. So you will still have to replace the logger line in your code with this:

```
 var morgan = require('morgan');
 app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

This will give you the ability to use a logging module on your app if you want to do it. This was a real pain in the butt and took a while to figure out. Cheers!